# PHP: Break loop and then continue?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm having a problem with the WordPress posts loop. I'd like to break down the post loop, to add some HTML div tags in the post. For example, I'm trying to add a div `.wrap` around the posts after first post. As it's to wrap the posts, so it should be only once.

The problem is that the `.wrap` div is being repeated because of the loop. How can I break the loop, and add the `.wrap` div only once and then continue the loop?

Here's my code:

```
while ($wp_query->have_posts()) :

    $wp_query->the_post(); 
    if($wp_query->current_post <= 1){ ?>
        <div class="x">
        .. post 1
        </div>
    <?php }
    if($wp_query->current_post > 1){ ?>
        <div class="wrap"> <!-- should be only once -->
            <div class="y">
            .. post 2
            </div>

            <div class="y">
            .. post 3
            </div>
        </div><!-- should be only once -->
    <?php } ?>

endwhile;
```

Comment: you don't have to break the loop

Comment: Yeah, the wrap output code doesn't loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php
while ($wp_query->have_posts()) :
    $wp_query->the_post(); 
    if($wp_query->current_post <= 1){ ?>
        <div class="x">
        .. post 1
        </div>
        <div class="wrap"> <!-- should be only once -->
    <?php 
    $is_wrapped = 1;
    }
    if($wp_query->current_post > 1){ ?>
        <div class="y">
          .. post 2, then post 3, ...
        </div>
    <?php } 
endwhile;?>
<?php if (!empty($is_wrapped)){ ?>
        </div><!-- should be only once -->
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use an iterator index, like this:

```
$i = 0;
while (...) {
    if ($i == 1) {
       // actions you need to do only once
    }

    ...
    $i++
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="x">

while ($wp_query->have_posts()) :
    $wp_query->the_post();
    <--print post-->
    if($wp_query->current_post <= 1){
        </div><div class="y">
    }
endwhile;

</div>
```

You will get an empty `<div class="x" />` if there's no post and an empty `<div class="y" />` if there's only one post. But may be that's feasible in your case...

---

edit: example

```
<?php
$wp_query = new WPDummy; 

echo '<div class="x">';    
while ($wp_query->have_posts()) :
    $wp_query->the_post();
    $wp_query->the_content();
    if($wp_query->current_post <= 1){
        echo '</div>', "\n",'<div class="y">';
    }
endwhile;
echo '</div>';

// boilerplate
class WPDummy {
    public $current = null;
    public $current_post = 0;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->posts = array( array('content'=>'A'),array('content'=>'B'),array('content'=>'C'),array('content'=>'D') );
    }

    public function have_posts() {
        return false!=current($this->posts);
    }

    public function the_post() {
        $this->current_post+=1;
        $this->current = current($this->posts);
        next($this->posts);
    }

    public function the_content() {
        echo '<span class="content">', $this->current['content'], '</span>';
    }
}
```

prints

```
<div class="x"><span class="content">A</span></div>
<div class="y"><span class="content">B</span><span class="content">C</span><span class="content">D</span></div>
```

Comment: my question is to add an additional div wrap inside the loop only once.