# Does "break continue" exist in PHP?

Tags: php, break, continue

For the context for this question please see my [recent post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38571807/where-can-i-find-the-algorithm-used-to-write-each-php-built-in-function). In the function below, a `break continue` would allow me to omit the last `if` condition. (see the comment in the inner for loop)

```
function strposHypothetical($haystack, $needle) {

    $haystackLength = strlen($haystack);
    $needleLength   = strlen($needle);//for this question let's assume > 0

    $pos = false;

    for($i = 0; $i < $haystackLength; $i++) {
        for($j = 0; $j < $needleLength; $j++) {
            $thisSum = $i + $j;
            if (($thisSum > $haystackLength) || 
                ($needle[$j] !== $haystack[$thisSum])) 
                  break; 
            // if I could "break continue" I could omit the 
            // if ($j === $needleLength) 
            // below and just write $pos = $i; break;       
        }
        if ($j === $needleLength) {
            $pos = $i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $pos;
}
```

I have seen somewhat similar posts such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13121076/php-break-loop-and-then-continue) one that don't quite answer my question. I do not want to refactor the function above. I don't need `break 2` nor `continue 2`. Note `break 2` would not work in the inner loop because necessary iterations in the outer for loop would be missed. `continue 2` also fails because the inner for loop needs to iterate to the end of the needle. Is `break continue` possible in PHP?

***Note*** I have tried this and got a Fatal Error so I assume either the answer is "No" or I implemented it incorrectly.

***Note 2*** By "break continue" I mean break the inner loop then continue the outer

Comment: What woud you expect `break continue` to actually do? Its kinda contradictory

Comment: Breaks out of the inner and goes to next iteration of outer, with the continue skipping the $pos and break below it, which is what I would like to do

Comment: @self can you show more of this, it is not mentioned in the PHP manual

Comment: forgive me for being obtuse, but why doesn't `break` break out of the inner and continue with the outer?

Comment: It does but I want to immediately skip past the lines below the inner for loop on unsuccessful matches (inner loop) and also skip the final if conditional on a successful match

Comment: `By "break continue" I mean break the inner loop then continue the outer` . The keyword `break` (within the inner for loop) does this anyway, ceasing the inner for loop and carrying on the next itteration of the outer for loop. What's wrong with this?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with it - I just have a massive application I am trying to streamline (literally) in any possible way. A "break continue" would allow the loop to skip a final if condition in the outer loop. If the outer loop has tens of thousands of iterations, skipping the final if would mean something (albeit still not much :)   ) My question is a legitimate question and based on the responses, I am assuming the answer is "No"

Answer (score 3):

there is continue  (skip)

> ```
> <?php
>   while (list($key, $value) = each($arr)) {
>     if (!($key % 2)) { // skip even members
>        continue;
>     }
>     do_something_odd($value);
> }
>
> ?>
> ```

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php

```
for($i = 0; $i < $haystackLength; $i++) {
    for($j = 0; $j < $needleLength; $j++) {
        $thisSum = $i + $j;
        if (($thisSum > $haystackLength) || 
            ($needle[$j] !== $haystack[$thisSum])) 
            continue;   
    }
    if ($j === $needleLength) {
        $pos = $i;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: haha, no I meant my comment was deleted by me because the issue I raised is no longer present in the answer. as in that's a good thing `:-)`

Comment: @Martin  It 'a fun situation anyway thanks for the tip

Comment: @scaisEdge this has the same problem my initial refactor had, it adds extra comparisons as the inner for loop no longer exits when the needle does not match, but now keeps going. It also no longer works because the only thing which exits the inner loop is $j maxing out.

Comment: @ReidJohnson  Mine is just an example and a suggestion .. I will not go into the merits of the application problems or the OP application logic

Comment: Noted, just noting that your suggested code doesn't work in the slightest, no matter the merits of the original code.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, in PHP there is no such construct as "break continue", however, by moving all of the logic into the inner loop, you can avoid flags and the need for "break continue" entirely. Doesn't really simplify the logic at all, thought, so YMMV.

```
function strposHypothetical( $haystack, $needle ){
    $haystackLength = strlen( $haystack );
    $needleLength = strlen( $needle );

    $pos = false;

    for( $i = 0; $i < $haystackLength; $i++ ){
        for( $j = 0; $j < $needleLength; $j++ ){
            $thisSum = $i + $j;
            if( ( $thisSum > $haystackLength )
                || ( $needle[ $j ] !== $haystack[ $thisSum ] ) )
                break;
            else if( $j === $needleLength ){
                $pos = $i;
                break 2;
            }
        }
    }

    return $pos;
}
```

To address performance, you could even refactor this to, adds a little performance by not storing the result of $i + $j in a variable, but does get rid of that extra variable and makes $pos flag-like:

```
function strposHypothetical( $haystack, $needle ){
    $haystackLength = strlen( $haystack );
    $needleLength = strlen( $needle );

    $pos = false;

    for($i = 0; $i < $haystackLength; $i++) {
        $pos = $i;
        for($j = 0; $j < $needleLength; $j++) {
            if(
                ( $pos + $j > $haystackLength )
                || ( $needle[ $j ] !== $haystack[ $pos + $j ] )
            ){
                $pos = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if( $pos !== false )
            break;
    }

    return $pos;
}
```

Got some time to think last night, and this refactor should get the most performance by forcing the comparisons and assigns that the for loop is already performing to do most of the work. It also shortens the code quite a bit;

```
function strposHypothetical( $haystack, $needle ){
    $haystackLength = strlen( $haystack );
    $needleLength = strlen( $needle );

    for( $i = $haystackLength, $pos = false; $i >= 1 && $pos === false; $i-- ){
        for( $j = $needleLength - 1, $pos = $i - 1; $j >= 0 && $pos !== false; $j-- ){
            $pos--;
            if( $pos < 0 || $needle[ $j ] !== $haystack[ $pos ] )
                $pos = false;
        }
    }

    return $pos;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but respectfully, this is actually worse because now the if($j === $needleLength) comparison is not done $haystackLength times (max), but $haystackLength * $needleLength times (max).

Comment: I know. That's why I put YMMV. It does however, get the notion of break continue out of the code. There really isn't much you can do with the code as constructed to remove that notion without complete refactoring and you said you didn't want that. Figured some code was better than just saying there isn't a break continue or giving the obnoxious refactoring of removing all of the code and just putting `return strpos( $haystack, $needle);`

Comment: OK...appreciated. I do understand how a popular response on SO is to just say "Your code is bad - what you should have done is this...". Up vote on your comment and response (because your code does work).

Comment: For the second function, the returned position should not be $i + $j, the position is $i because this is the position on the haystack. $i + $j is for matching needle to haystack once you've locked onto a position $i on the haystack

Comment: It would indeed work perfectly there, and I too have found myself wishing for things in PHP (and many other languages) that just don't exist. I added a second example that removes the performance thing and, as an added bonus, gets rid of a variable. Doesn't really remove any of the logic, but does, arguably, make things a little tighter.

Comment: You are indeed right. Will have it fixed in a jiff.